# LAME on a Shared Hosting?

Tags: linux

Hi is it possible to install LAME on a shared hosting via FTP or browser install? I need to convert wav file to mp3 they're small 10-90kb 2-3 second clips. If there is another way without LAME I'd be interested in knowing how. I don't have shell access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible in theory, but depends on your provider. They may or may not provide what you need to do this.

Note that in some parts of the world (for example, the United States), there may be patent issues involved with using an mp3 encoder.

Comment: Other issues might be that it takes up lots of CPU and the provider may not like this either.

Comment: the CPU usage shouldn't be noticeable converting a 10-90kb wav to mp3 shouldn't take more than 1-2sec if that. any tips on how to install it without shell?