# How to install LAME on redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

How do I install LAME on a RedHat server... i tried

```
yum install lame lame-mp3x 
No package lame available.
No package lame-mp3x available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to get it to install with

wget http://easynews.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/lame/lame-3.97.tar.gz

Answer (score 5):

1. make sure you have the tools necessary to build from source:

   `yum update`

   `yum install gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool yasm nasm git subversion`
2. Get the tarball for version you want here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/
3. upload the tarball somewhere on your server
4. cd /path/to/lame-3.99.5 (or whatever version you downloaded)
5. ./configure
6. make && make install
7. ldconfig

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the problem I hinted at in my [answer to your other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/210665/lame-on-a-shared-hosting/210668#210668): lame uses algorithms covered by patent, and you may not be able to use it legally for what you're planning to do without paying licensing fees. See [here for a bit more](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Lame_Installation#Legal_issues), and also [this big list of mp3 patents](http://www.tunequest.org/a-big-list-of-mp3-patents/20070226/).

For this reason, Red Hat, as a US-based company, can't really provide it for you. Your best bet is to either build it from source or to get it from a non-US third-party repository, keeping in mind that your *use* is probably not legal no matter where you get the software. (Is it possible for your application to use a different, [unencumbered](http://www.vorbis.com/) audio compression technology?)

Comment: the person I'm setting this for wants mp3. was able to get it to install though