# Installing Lame on Amazon Linux - command not found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, installation, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install Lame on Amazon Linux. I've downloaded `lame-3.99.5.tar.gz`, uploaded it to the server, and tried to install it.

I followed [this example](https://serverfault.com/a/610748/147006):

1. make sure you have the tools necessary to build from source:

   `yum update`

   `yum install gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool yasm nasm git subversion`
2. Get the tarball for version you want here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/
3. upload the tarball somewhere on your server
4. cd /path/to/lame-3.99.5 (or whatever version you downloaded)
5. ./configure
6. make && make install
7. ldconfig

Steps 6 results in errors:

```
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libmp3lame.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/test/lame/lame-3.99.5/libmp3lame'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/lame/lame-3.99.5/libmp3lame'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/test/lame/lame-3.99.5/libmp3lame'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

This is executed using sudo. I've tried to repeat this as root, and then no errors returned.

Step 7 returns nothing, but maybe that's how it should work?

When I try to run `lame` I get `command not found`.

**How can I get lame running?**

Comment: Not tempted to just use the rpm?

Comment: Any method that works is fine, whether it's yum, rpm, rpmforge or from source. But I'm not sure what rpm to use with Amazon Linux. I regret not having used Centos, but this is what I have to use for the moment.

Comment: It is essentially RHEL/Centos

Comment: Essentially yes, but still... When I google for `rpm lame` I get the following page https://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lame My best guess here is `Mageia Cauldron for x86_64` or `Mageia 5 for x86_64`, but this makes me unsure. I'm not that familiar with installing via RPM. I suppose this is about Centos 5 or 6? Our Amazon Linux is updated to the last version.

Comment: I don't know lame too well, just try one, it'll either work or not.

Answer (score 1):

You encountered the error `Permission denied` installing lame when running `make install`.

This happened because the `make install` tried to create the file `/usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0` and could not do so, as shown in your error message.

> ```
> /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0': Permission denied
> ```

This step in the process needs to be run with `sudo`, i.e.:

```
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has installed fine, but in the prefix of `/usr/local/bin` - it's likely that this prefix is not on your run PATH.

Try calling it explicitly: `/usr/local/bin/lame`

If that works, then just add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH.

usually in `~/.bashrc` add...

`PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin`